# Use SVG and Javascript to create Chart Generator Web App (no third party packages or libraries)

Tags: javascript, svg

My professor has tasked us with creating a web app that generates a bar, pie, and line chart using only javascript and SVG.  No third-party packages or libraries are allowed. I've been stuck on this for weeks and can't seem to figure it out.

Here is a good example of what I am trying to create http://nasir9bd.github.io/generate-chartjs/ the author uses jquery and chartjs, which I am not allowed to use.

If anyone can point me to a tutorial on how to create this using only javascript and SVG? please I am going mad! I've tried coding it myself and only got so far. I've tried tutorials, but all only use libraries or other languages.

Comment: Have you seen [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial)?

Answer (score 0):

I learned from [Mozilla tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial).
. You have to be patient reading from scratch,

First, learn the 2D position of the shape (x,y)

Second, learn the basic shapes (Rectangle, Circle, Ellipse, Line, Polyline, Polygon, Path).

Third, customize and decorate these shapes with Fill, Stroke and Gradients.

Examples:

- To draw a bar chart, draw an `<svg>` element with `<rec>` elements inside it.
- To draw a pie chart, draw an `<svg>` element with `<path>` elements inside.
- To draw a line chart, draw an `<svg>` element with an `<polyline>` element inside.

Try to read the [basic shapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Basic_Shapes) section, do the examples, you'll get 50% of the idea. Good luck!

Comment: thanks yeah, I've read the mdn documentation and went through the professor lecture notes a few times.  I can create the charts statically but when it comes to making them dynamic I run into issues. Also, think my chart scale intervals are off. might have to go back to the drawing board. I'll re-read mdn docs maybe I missed something.

cc: @fixiabis

Comment: Okay, so try this way: draw a static chart using SVG (x column, y column, bars), then try to make a function out of it. Then come back to StackOverflow when you're stuck with your code (as an example).
Otherwise, you'll get general answers like mine and you can't go any further.